# Query MySQL with multiple identifier

Tags: java, mysql

I have a MySQL table with more than a million rows like this:

```
id (BIGINT) | id_other (INT)
24334501    | 20123
24334501    | 20324
24334501    | 20111
24334500    | 20123
24334500    | 20324
24334510    | 20111
....
```

From this table, I want to build a map from a list of ids like this:

```
 id_other -> count of id
```

my query is: `"select * from lsh where id = ?"`

To perform those queries, I created an index for the column `ìd`

Now I want to get a list of all `id_other` from a list of `id`.
Currently I have this code:

```
for (Long id : ids{ // ids has a size between 2000 and 8000
                statement.setLong(1, id);

                ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();

                while(rs.next()) {
                    int idOther = rs.getInt("id_other");
                    if(!map.containsKey(idOther)){
                        map.put(idOther, new AtomicInteger(0));
                    }
                    map.get(idOther).incrementAndGet();
                }
            }
```

any ideas how to perform this?

**UPDATE:**
Now I have this query: `select id_other, count(*) FROM lsh  WHERE id ? GROUP BY id_other` .
I execute the query with:
Array array = connection.createArrayOf("BIGINT", values.toArray());
            statement.setArray(1, array);
            final ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();

But now I get this exception for `connection.createArrayOf`: `java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException`

thank you

Comment: You may want to look `group_concat` function of mysql.

Comment: You mean you want something along the lines of `select id_other, count(*) FROM lsh GROUP BY id_other WHERE id IN ([8000 values here])`?

Comment: yes, that's it :) is there a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like the following ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/088b7f/4)):

```
SELECT id_other, COUNT(*) AS total_ids , GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS list_id
FROM lsh
WHERE id_other IN (20111, 20123, 20324)
GROUP BY id_other
ORDER BY id_other;
```

Result:

```
id_other    total_ids   list_id
20111       2           24334501,24334510
20123       2           24334500,24334501
20324       2           24334500,24334501
```

Comment: yes, something in this kind. But how to build this IN clousel in java? I updated my qestion

Comment: You can create a temporary (memory) table and fill that from java.

Comment: I am not a Java guy but maybe you need a list if you don't know the total size of the array (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776644/java-how-do-i-initialize-an-array-size-if-its-unknown).